# Get Region Id given Region Code and country id

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, factory, country-regions

I need to get the region_id given the region_code and the country_id, but I cannot manage to achieve it. 
I've tried using the countryFactory and the regionFactory, but i do not understand what i'm doing wrong.

I have something like this

in the constructor the RegionFactory

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory
) {
    $this->_regionFactory = $regionFactory;
}

function getRegionIdByCode($code){


 $region = $this->_regionFactory->create()
            ->loadByCode($code,$country_id)->getFirstItem();
...
}
//where code is correctly calculated based on a csv with all italian regions
```

Cannot manage to work with the $region object. I need to do something like 
$region->getRegionId()

Is it possible??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has to work

```
$region = $this->_regionFactory->create();
$regionId = $region->loadByCode($code, $country_id)->getId();
```

Comment: Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/325882/57334 @Nikolas

Answer (score 5):

Try below code:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$region = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\Region')
                        ->loadByCode('CA', 'US');
print_r($region->getData());
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [region_id] => 12
    [country_id] => US
    [code] => CA
    [default_name] => California
    [name] => California
)
```

> **Note:** Please do not use Object Manager. Instead create function and then call it.

Comment: i accepted the @Nikolas solution, as it is the one not using object manager, but regionFactory correctly as I needed, even though this is going to work as well and can also be translated with regionFactory like this
 `$region = $this->_regionFactory->create()
            ->loadByCode($code,$country_id)->getData("region_id");`
But a +1 for the suggestion

Comment: How get all region code and names from country id?

Comment: Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/325882/57334 @Abhishek Panchal

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    namespace MODULENAMESPACE\MODULENAME\Helper;

    use \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory;
    use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

    class Data extends AbstractHelper {
           protected $_regionFactory;
           protected $_logger;

           public function __construct(
              RegionFactory $regionFactory,
              LoggerInterface $logger
           ){
              $this->_regionFactory = $regionFactory;
              $this->_logger = $logger;
           }

            /**
             * Gets the region data from the two digit state code
             * @param $state - Two letter state code
             *
             * @return array [region_id],[country_id],[code],[default_name],[name]
             */

            public function getRegionDataByCode($state, $countryId = 'US') {
                try {
                    $region   = $this->_regionFactory->create();
                    $regionData = $region->loadByCode($state, $countryId);
                    return $regionData;
                }
                catch(\Exception $e) {
                    $this->_logger->critical($e->getMessage());
                    return false;
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

*** Get code ***

```
call helper
<?php
    $helper = $this->dataHelper; //construct it before call
    $helper->getRegionDataByCode('TX')->getRegionId();
    //[region_id],[country_id],[code],[default_name]
?>
```