# Magento2.4: How to get Region name by Zip code?

Tags: magento2, zipcode, regions

I need to get the region name based on ZIP/Postal code. My code is below but its not working. Can anyone please help to get the region name by zip code?

```
$postcode = "560100";
$regionCollection = $this->regionCollectionFactory->create();
$regionCollection->addRegionCodeFilter($postcode)->setPageSize(1);

if ($regionCollection->getSize()) {
    $region = $regionCollection->getFirstItem();
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I think it's not possible with Magento Code you need to call Custom Google API

Comment: Thak you @RonakRathod for replying. Could you please highlight some examples?

Comment: Can you please check this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197473/get-region-id-given-region-code-and-country-id

Comment: @RanaZain I have tried this now and it's not working with the zip code. It seems the method loadByCode will only work with region code parameter and not zip codes. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Yes, I added an answer can you please check?

Answer (score 1):

## **It's not possible with Magento Code you need to call Custom Google API**

**Here is the Example with the Google Map API**

[How to get Google API Key?](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20Google%20Maps%20Platform%20%3E%20Credentials%20page.&text=On%20the%20Credentials%20page%2C%20click,your%20newly%20created%20API%20key.)

### **You need to call the API for getting Region Name by Zip-Code**

**API :** https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=560100&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCQ688uhIYTXi4kphAvgTq0Lf25dg62198

**Response:**

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "560100",
               "short_name" : "560100",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bengaluru",
               "short_name" : "Bengaluru",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bengaluru Urban",
               "short_name" : "Bengaluru Urban",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bangalore Division",
               "short_name" : "Bangalore Division",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Karnataka",
               "short_name" : "KA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Bengaluru, Karnataka 560100, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 12.8751739,
                  "lng" : 77.71305129999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 12.8193509,
                  "lng" : 77.6091
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 12.8498481,
               "lng" : 77.6544856
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 12.8751739,
                  "lng" : 77.71305129999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 12.8193509,
                  "lng" : 77.6091
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJCa-XPptsrjsRL5utZGjUjOk",
         "postcode_localities" : [
            "Andapura",
            "Basapura",
            "Bengaluru",
            "Beratena Agrahara",
            "Bettadasanapura",
            "Bhovi Palya",
            "Bommasandra",
            "Bommasandra Industrial Area",
            "Chikkathoguru",
            "Chinthalamadivala",
            "Daadys Gaarden Layout",
            "Doddanagamangala Village",
            "Doddathoguru",
            "Electronic City",
            "Gottamaranahalli",
            "Gulimangala",
            "Hulimangala",
            "LHR layout",
            "Maragondanahalli",
            "Mylasandra",
            "Podu",
            "RS Gardens",
            "Rayasandra",
            "S.Bingipura",
            "Singena Agrahara",
            "Thirupalya",
            "Vaddara Palya",
            "Vidyanagar",
            "Vittasandra"
         ],
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

## **Note : You need to change key with your API key.**